# Is there a general term for a pairing of tables where one has header information and the other has detail lines?

Tags: database, database-design, theory

Is there a general term for a pairing of tables where one has header information and the other has detail lines?

For example, a pair of tables describing sales orders, or a pair storing bill of materials data.

Comment: Hi. Because you are a newcomer, I don't know if you read the whole site ... Do you know you can vote for useful answers (press the up arrow), and even accept one as a best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that it is a good practice to use consistent naming conventions in your database for these types of tables.  Doesn't really matter what names, consistency is really the key.  The goal is to have a general idea of what the table holds based on the name.  Some I've seen:

(Assume the table holds Products)

Product -- ProductDetail

ProductHeader -- ProductDetail

Product -- ProductLines

For me, Parent-Child names imply a hierarchical relationship, which is a whole 'nother ball of wax.

Comment: I think Master/Detail is the best answer, since it's at the correct level of abstraction.  It's true that there's a parent/child hierarchy, since each detail/line has exactly one parent, but that's a matter of implementation.

Answer (score 4):

One-To-Many describes the "numbers".

But one could prefer **Parent-Child** in some contexts, typically when the Child always has a Parent...

Answer (score 3):

I think it is called a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Also, Master-Detail.